# What is an Instant in JHipster JDL?

Tags: date, jhipster, localdate, jdl

Where can I find any information about an instant in JDL? And how does it relate to a Date format...?

Besides this: https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/

Available field types and constraints
Here are the types supported in the JDL:

```
SQL          MongoDB    Cassandra   Validations
Instant      Instant    Instant     required

LocalDate   LocalDate   required    required
ZonedDateTime   ZonedDateTime       required
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the JDL data types are simply Java types.
So an "Instant" refers to a Java "Instant" as described in the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)

> An instantaneous point on the time-line.
>
> This class models a single instantaneous point on the time-line. This might be used to record event time-stamps in the application.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Nice to meet you instant, never heard of you before .-)